# Sprite Solution for Slow OnHover Event & 2 Images

Tags: html

One of the buttons on my site has a slow response for the OnHover, and Im not sure why this is happening.

http://davincispainting.com  then click on the upper-right button "Click for Quick Connect"

[image]

```
<div id='contact-form'>
    <a class="contact" href="#"></a>
</div>

a.contact {
background-image: url("/images/Home/RapidButton2.png");
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
text-align: center;
width: 165px;
height: 27px;
}

a.contact:hover {
background-image: url("/images/Home/RapidButtonHov2.png");
}
```

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? Have you tried with other graphics? I've checked the site out in Google Chrome and Firefox (both on OS X) with a decent internet connection and see noting wrong: the `onhover` triggers just fine, no lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be the `hover` image has to be downloaded first at first hover, that delays (a bit on slow connections).

Try making it a **sprite**. IE. merge the two images in one bigger image where both images are stacked.
use the `background-position` property to shift the big image according the hover state.

like RapidButton-sprite.png becomes:

[image: sprite sample]

and the css:

```
a.contact {
  background-image: url("/images/Home/RapidButton-sprite.png");
  background-position:left bottom; // or 0px -27px;
  .................
}

a.contact:hover {
  background-position:left top; // or 0px 0px;
  .................
}
```

A nice tutorial is found **[here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)**

Comment: Mind that I switched the order of the two images, normally you would put the default state on top of course ;) so the background-position's have to flipped as well

Comment: I tried this approach and since there is no loading of the hover image, theres no delay onHover.